# Making an Ajax request using data from previous ajax request

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am attempting to write an Angular page to communicate with my Nodejs server, but I have ran into a snag.

I need to use multiple Ajax requests that rely on the data from previous ajax requests to work.

So Ajax request #1 provides data that is used by all other Ajax requests, and Ajax request #2 uses data from ajax request #1 to get the data that Ajax request #3 needs.

Since Angular is asynchronous, how can I make my script wait for the data from the first one before making the next ajax call.

id = ajax()

Wait for data

token = ajax(id)

wait for data

gametoken = ajax(id, token)

wait for data

Comment: Basically you need to read about angularJS promise. And use the $http service to chain promises. See this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284403/chaining-ajax-calls-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chandermani is correct, just remember to make sure to make the variables you need available in the scope that you need it.

```
var id,token,gametoken;
$http.get('http://host.com/first')
   .then(function(result){
       id=result;
       return $http.get('http://host.com/second/'+id);
    }
    .then(function(result){
        token = result
        return $http.get('http://host.com/third'+id+'/'+token);
    }
    .then(function(result){
        gametoken = result;
        //Do other code here that requires id,token and gametoken
    }
```

EDIT:
You don't have to chain the promises.  If you want to make a call at a later date and you want to make sure the promises have resolved you can use $q.all();

```
var id,token,gametoken;
var p1 = $http.get('http://host.com/first')
   .then(function(result){
       id=result;
    }

// Later on to make your new second call
 $q.all([p1]).then(function(){
      //Make second call knowing that the first has finished.
 }
```

$q.all() takes an array so you can put in multiple promises if you want and it will wait until they have all resolved.

Comment: This doesn't help me resolve the problem, because I'm unsure of when the next request for data will happen. It could happen 3 seconds later, or 10 minutes later, depending on what the user chooses to do.