# How does one chain successive/consecutive $http posts in angular?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and am learning as I go along. How do I chain successive $http posts? I need reponse data from the first $http POST to use in the second $http POST, of which I'll also need the response which this second POST returns.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://yoururl.com/api',
    data: '{"field_1": "foo", "field_2": "bar"}',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).then(function(resp) {

   $scope.data_needed = resp.data_needed;
    // Can't possibly do another $http post here using the data I need, AND get its reponse?
    // Would lead to a nested relationship, instead of adjacent chaining.

}, function(err) {
    // Handle error here.
});
```

I've found out that it isn't an option to chain another $http post to the last line of code with another `.then(function(resp) {});`, for the same reason (referring to 1st comment in code block above).

Any advice? All I can seem to find are examples of chaining $http GETs, which do not involve getting and using a response. Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37175801/2518285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
$http({...})
    .then(
        function success1(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            $scope.xxx = data.xxx;
            return $http({...});
        },
        function error1(response) {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    )
    .then(
        function success2(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            $scope.yyy = data.yyy;
        },
        function error2(response) {
            // handle error
        }
    );
```

When a `then()` function returns a promise (the `return $http(...)` part), the chained `then()` gets called with the resolved value of the second promise. Also note the `return $q.reject(...)` part, necessary for the flow to proceed to the second *error* function, instead of the second success function.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Now I just need to figure out how to properly express the http header `-H "Authorization: JWT <your_token>"` in angular... Thanks again!