# Synchronize POSTs to an API in Angular

Tags: ajax, angularjs, synchronous

I'm trying to synchronize my POSTs to an endpoint in Angular. I did see some examples of doing a synchronized GET but had trouble understanding the examples well enough to apply them to POSTs.

The POSTs are pretty simple, at least from my perspective as the front-end developer. I send an object with an parent group ID and a sub group ID to a /parentgroups endpoint. On the backend, however, async calls cause the data to get overwritten.

Apologies for lack of an example, but I am pretty far from having one that's close to working how I need. My code is still async and a loop over calls to $http.post().

Comment: So to be clear, you want to do a POST, wait for that to complete, then do another POST?

Comment: Yeah, I know it sounds like a strange thing to do, but the backend developer insists that this is the best way to make it work.

Comment: Is it a fixed number of POSTS you need to do or will the number vary? $http.post() returns a promise so you could chain them all together, using the .success() handler that each POST will call (i recommend using the .success over the .then as it will unpack the returned data for you).

Comment: Actually, this post explains it quite well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284403/chaining-ajax-calls-in-angularjs

Comment: Apologies for forgetting that detail, jonnyknowsbest... it's not a fixed number. That's why the chained promises example doesn't help me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually cannot do real synchronous (as in blocking) http calls in Angular, it forces you do use async. If you can't do it with callbacks then you have a problem with your architecture that the entire team should focus on solving **ASAP**. If your current architecture requires the frontend to do blocking calls then your architecture is quite simply broken and needs to be fixed.

Anyway, while I recommend against it you could always register your request in a list, and then in each callback you pop the next request from the list and run it. That way you can just keep pushing requests into the list without knowing how many there will be. Something like this (untested, but the general principle should work):

```
var requestList = [];
requestList.push(function() {
    $http.post('/someUrl', {})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // Remove the next request from list and call it
        requestList.shift()();
    });
});
requestList.push(function() {
    $http.post('/someOtherUrl', {})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // Remove the next request from list and call it
        requestList.shift()();
    });
});

// Start the first request
requestList.shift()();
```

This is fairly clean, but still a bit of a hack. It would probably work fine but I would be taking a good long look at why the API forces you to do something like this.

Comment: Very clever! Also, I agree with you on the bad parts. Your comments also helped me get the backend developer to make changes for me to prevent the need for this. Thank you very much.