# Calling second request after first one is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question about requests.I make first request then I suppose first onSuccess method will be runnning but program make second request immediately.How can i handle it? `Context.getAlarmGroupById` is called 2 times immediately.
my code:

```
        function loadAll () {
        Context.getAlarmGroupChainById({
            id: $stateParams.id
        }, onSuccess, onError);


            function onSuccess(data, headers) {
            vm.temp=data; 
            var numberGroupChain=vm.temp.length;
            for(var i=0; i<numberGroupChain; i++){
                vm.location.push(vm.temp[i].location);
                vm.alarmChainList.push({name: vm.location[i],active:null,totalAlarmGroupNumber:null});             
                //loadData(vm.temp[i].id);
                asyncLoop(vm.temp[i].id);
              }
            }


            function onError(error) {
              AlertService.error(error.data.message);
            }

        var index = 0;

        function asyncLoop(chainId) {
            if(index >= vm.temp.length) {
                return;
            }
         Context.getAlarmGroupById({
             id:chainId
         }, onSuccess, onError);


             function onSuccess(data,headers){
                 index++;
                 asyncLoop();
             }

             function onError(data,headers){
                 index++;
                 asyncLoop();
             }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546248/chain-angular-http-calls-properly

Comment: Don't call a service in a loop. Make a method Car.getGroupIds(vm.temp) that returns a list that you can filter.

Comment: I made a new function but problem is still exist

Comment: for(var i=0; i<numberGroupChain; i++){
                vm.location.push(vm.temp[i].location);
                vm.alarmChainList.push({name: vm.location[i],active:null,totalAlarmGroupNumber:null});             
                //loadData(vm.temp[i].id);
                
              }
            }; asyncLoop(vm.temp[i].id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly:** `Car.getGroupId` is an asynchronous function. So you have to ensure that the previous call is completed, before the next call.

**Secondly:** The recursive function is created for replacing the loop, after the `success` function and index increment, the recursive function is called to ensure your required requirement.

**Third:** Change the calling sequence of `asyncLoop(vm.temp[i].id);` after loop:

**Finally:**

Please use the following code:

```
function loadAll () {

    var index = 0;

    function asyncLoop(chainId) {
        if(index >= vm.temp.length) {
            return;
        }
     Context.getAlarmGroupById({
         id:vm.temp[index].id
     }, onSuccess, onError);


         function onSuccess(data,headers){
             index++;
             asyncLoop();
         }

         function onError(data,headers){
             index++;
             asyncLoop();
         }
    }

    function onSuccessParent(data, headers) {
        vm.temp=data; 
        var numberGroupChain=vm.temp.length;
        for(var i=0; i<numberGroupChain; i++){
            vm.location.push(vm.temp[i].location);
            vm.alarmChainList.push({name: vm.location[i],active:null,totalAlarmGroupNumber:null});             
            //loadData(vm.temp[i].id);

          }
          asyncLoop();
    }


    function onErrorParent(error) {
          AlertService.error(error.data.message);
    }

    Context.getAlarmGroupChainById({
        id: $stateParams.id
    }, onSuccessParent, onErrorParent);
```

}

Comment: I cannot implement your code to my code:( function has to get a parameter but i cannot add it

Comment: loadData(vm.temp[i].id); id need not to pass as vm is global variable.

Comment: It is not working.It call 2 times again before enter the onSuccess.I loaded last update code.Can you help me?

Comment: Context.getAlarmGroupById is called two times before onSuccess method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure JavaScript way to do this and it works perfectly fine. Use [Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). Do like below:

```
var request1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

request1.then(function(value) {
  // make request2 here
});
```