# Grouping futures from $http callbacks

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to expand data from an API.

Let's get an example. The API would return:

```
GET /group/1
{ "id": 1, "items": [1, 2, 3] }

GET /item/1
{ "id": 1, "name: "Item 1" }
```

I want to map groups to expand items inside:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "expanded_items": [
    { "id": 1, "name: "Item 1" },
    { "id": 2, "name: "Item 2" },
    { "id": 3, "name: "Item 3" }
  ]
}
```

I can't find out how to handle the callbacks to map the nested items:

```
$http.get("/group/1").then(function(result) {
  var group = result.data;
  group.items.map(function(itemId) {
    $http.get("/item/" + itemid);
    // And then... ?
  });
});
```

The `then` callback does not return a result. And I'm not sure I should fill an array of futures out of the `map` function. Should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain your requests using `.then()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16285000/3835632) and you can use `$q.all` along with this.For your case the promises should be chained like as follows

```
$http.get("/group/1").then(function(result) {
  var group = result.data;
  var itemPromises=group.items.map(function(itemId) {
     return $http.get("/item/" + itemid);
  });
  return $q.all(itemPromises).then(function(itemResponses){
     return {
         "id":1,
         "expandedItems":itemResponses
      }
  });
}).then(function(requiredOutput){
    console.log(requiredOutput);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `$q.all()`.

Something like:

```
$http.get("/group/1").then(function(result) {
  var group = result.data;
  var itemResponses = [];
  group.items.forEach(function(itemId) {
    itemResponses.push($http.get("/item/" + itemid));
  });
  return $q.all(itemResponses);
}).then(function(responseDataArray) {
  var expandedObject = {id: 1, expanded_items: []}
  responseDataArray.forEach(function(data) {
    expandedObject.expanded_items(expanded_expandedObjectdata.result)
  });
  return expandedObject;
});
```

(Written from memory, not sure about the exact syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

You should **use $q service** of angular in this case.
Since $http is async by default hence it doesn't blocks execution if data is not yet arrived from server.
To block call you must use $q service.